# GTK+ adding references in MonoDevelop

Tags: gtk, reference, monodevelop

I am currently developing a GTK# application which will use a component to view a web page and make connection to an FTP server. So I found these two libraries, Webkit for viewing the web page and gFTP for the FTP connection.

Now I've added the packages using Synaptic Package Manager. And the package references are added to a folder called '/usr/lib/pkconfig/'. 
[image: Folder screenshot]

Apparently this should add the libraries to the references-list I can use from in MonoDevelop, but neither of them show up. =/

I already tried rebooting MonoDevelop and my computer (yes, I am a Windows-user), but it did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monodevelop only shows managed libraries (.net assemblies) in the references list. What you installed are native libraries which can't be directly used in gtk#.

Comment: Thanks I think I will just restart building the application using .NET. GTK+ does not seem like a good platform for this project.