# How to add external references in MonoDevelop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, monodevelop

I've downloaded a charting library called [NPlot](http://netcontrols.org/nplot/wiki/index.php?n=Main.HomePage) and I have no idea how to add it as a reference in a GTK# application I'm currently making in MonoDevelop. There is no option in the **Edit References** window that you could add an external reference apart from the listed ones.

How do you add an external reference in MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 3):

Being fairly new to Ubuntu (consequently, to using apps), I found it quite challenging to grapple with the dilemma above. After hours of searching (almost half a day actually), I found the answer. I created this post for others who might be facing this problem too.

Before proceeding, make sure you have your `dll` file to add as a reference.

First, **create a .pc file** containing the following:

```
Name:  
Description:  
Version:  
Libs: -r:<where your dll is>
```

Example:

```
Name: NPlot
Description: Creates charts.
Version: 0.9.9.2
Libs: -r:/home/xxx/Downloads/NPlot/nplot-gtk-0.9.9.2/NPlot.dll
```

Hat tip to this [site](http://www.thebinaryidiot.com/archives/2010/09/26/monodevelop-mysql-connector-reference/).

Remember **where you've saved** your .pc file. I've saved my file in `/home/xxx/Documents`. Next, **copy the .pc file** to `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`. I'm not sure with other Linux distros, but Ubuntu is preventing me to directly copy paste the file to the folder, so I have to use this command on the terminal:

```
sudo cp <source> <destination>
```

Example:

```
sudo cp /home/xxx/Documents/NPlot.pc /usr/lib/pkgconfig
```

It is now included in the Edit References window.

[image: Nplot is now added to Edit References window]

If the reference does not show, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918858/gtk-adding-references-in-monodevelop).

Answer (score 2):

1. Unzip the NPlot zip file and extract the dll you need.
2. In the Edit References dialog select the .Net Assembly tab.
3. Click the Browse button and browse to the NPlot dll file and select Open.
4. Click OK on the Edit References dialog.

Comment: When I "hit" the Browse button , no file dialog shows up on Ubuntu 16.04 when running MonoDevelop 5.5 with Xamarin ASP.NET addin. May I ask why that is? Thank you.